# iter_rows only loops through the first cell, tinter with openpyxl on Mac

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, openpyxl

I'm trying to compare a username and password entry with my Excel database. 

If the username and password in the database match with the `"username_entry.get()"` and `"password_entry.get()"`, then you can enter in the app.

Anyone could help me please ?

```
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
sheet = workbook["Create_Account"]

for cell in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=sheet.max_row, min_col=2, max_col=3, values_only=True):
    if cell[0] == entry_usernamelog.get() and cell[1] == entry_passwordlog.get():
        entry_usernamelog.delete(0, tk.END)
        entry_passwordlog.delete(0, tk.END)
        frame_login.destroy()
        frame_menu.pack(pady=5)
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo(title="Error", message="Le nom d'utilisateur ou mot de passe saisi est incorrect.")
    
    break
```

Comment: `break` should be at the end of the `if` block and the `else` block should be same indentation of the `for` line.